Remove array from JSON when it appears
I receive a JSON and sometimes, not always, I can receive an array in "resources"  instead of a single value. I need to always transform this to a single value, keeping only the first one.
{
"result": {
"data": [
{
"postman": "12345",
"recordCase": "12",
"TypOfClient": "Small",
"active": "Yes",
"validFrom": "2020-09-03",
"activeGrades": [
{
"resources": "100",
"accounts": "1234551"
}
],
"validTo": "4712-12-31"
},
{
"postman": "12345",
"recordCase": "12",
"TypOfClient": "Small",
"active": "Yes",
"validFrom": "2020-09-03",
"activeGrades": [
{
"resources": ["100", "200", "500"],
"accounts": "1234551"
}
],
"validTo": "4712-12-31"
}
],
"lastPage": true
},
"status": "Finished"
}

desire result
{
"result": {
"data": [
{
"postman": "12345",
"recordCase": "12",
"TypOfClient": "Small",
"active": "Yes",
"validFrom": "2020-09-03",
"activeGrades": [
{
"resources": "100",
"accounts": "1234551"
}
],
"validTo": "2026-12-31"
},
{
"postman": "224499",
"recordCase": "13",
"TypOfClient": "Small",
"active": "Yes",
"validFrom": "2020-09-11",
"activeGrades": [
{
"resources": "100",
"accounts": "1234551"
}
],
"validTo": "2025-12-31"
}
],
"lastPage": true
},
"status": "Finished"
}

Is that possible? I tried a couple of things but it always erase the entire line or keeps all the values.

what language are you using and  what have you tried?

I'm using Nifi 1.7 and a Jolt Transformation, i tried something like this:
        "activeGrades": {
          "*": {
            "resources": "=toString(@(1,resources[0]))"
          }

but that's not compatible with that environment.

Please edit your question with the actual code you tried and the one challenge that presents you (not in comments which many may not read)

You can use a cardinality operation in this case.
"resources": "ONE" with cardinality means to pick the first element of array and create a single object out of it.
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "result": {
        "data": {
          "*": {
            "activeGrades": {
              "*": {
                "resources": "ONE"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Hope this helps you!
